# jQuery $.post Submission Doubling After Each POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to post information to a PHP file, and I have just realized that the post doubles up everytime. For example first time I press it, it will post once, when I go back and make changes to my form information and submit again it will post twice. If I do it again, it will post four times, then eight, sixteen and so on. Making my application extremely sluggish. I have posted the code for the button press below. Any idea of what may be causing the double post increase? BTW I used Firebug to find this glitch.

```
$("#preferenceSubmit").click(function() {

    var selected = $('#preferenceTabs').tabs().tabs('option', 'selected');

//  alert($('input:checkbox[name=dayNight-radio]:checked').val());

    // ----------------------------------- Simple Time Preference ---------------------------------------------- //
     //     e.preventDefault();
    // MONDAY, WEDNESDAY, FRIDAY --------------------------------
    MWFStart = convertTime($('#MWFStartHour').val(),$('#MWFStartMinute').val(),$('#MWFStartMeridian').val());
    MWFEnd = convertTime($('#MWFEndHour').val(),$('#MWFEndMinute').val(),$('#MWFEndMeridian').val());

    // TUESDAY, THURSDAY --------------------------------
    TRStart = convertTime($('#TRStartHour').val(),$('#TRStartMinute').val(),$('#TRStartMeridian').val());
    TREnd = convertTime($('#TREndHour').val(),$('#TREndMinute').val(),$('#TREndMeridian').val());

           // ----------------------------------- Advanced Time Preference ---------------------------------------------- //
    // MONDAY --------------------------------
    MStart = convertTime($('#MStartHour').val(),$('#MStartMinute').val(),$('#MStartMeridian').val());
    MEnd = convertTime($('#MEndHour').val(),$('#MEndMinute').val(),$('#MEndMeridian').val());


    // TUESDAY --------------------------------
    TStart = convertTime($('#TStartHour').val(),$('#TStartMinute').val(),$('#TStartMeridian').val());
    TEnd = convertTime($('#TEndHour').val(),$('#TEndMinute').val(),$('#TEndMeridian').val());


    // WEDNESDAY --------------------------------
    WStart = convertTime($('#WStartHour').val(),$('#WStartMinute').val(),$('#WStartMeridian').val());
    WEnd = convertTime($('#WEndHour').val(),$('#WEndMinute').val(),$('#WEndMeridian').val());


    // THURSDAY --------------------------------
    RStart = convertTime($('#RStartHour').val(),$('#RStartMinute').val(),$('#RStartMeridian').val());
    REnd = convertTime($('#REndHour').val(),$('#REndMinute').val(),$('#REndMeridian').val());


    // FRIDAY --------------------------------
    FStart = convertTime($('#FStartHour').val(),$('#FStartMinute').val(),$('#FStartMeridian').val());
    FEnd = convertTime($('#FEndHour').val(),$('#FEndMinute').val(),$('#FEndMeridian').val());

    // Since SEMESTER is a must for searching for classes, we must create some sort of error notifying the user of the issue. Same goes with adding NO classes.
    // Create IF statement, and check for an empty string.
    // Also create an error if Time Preference times are incorrect, for example, if Starting time > ending time is not valid.

    $.post('search.php', { 'searchClasses[]':tbl.fnGetData(), 'semester' :$('#term').val(), 'MWFStart' : MWFStart, 'MWFEnd' : MWFEnd, 'TRStart' : TRStart, 'TREnd' : TREnd, 'MStart' : MStart, 'MEnd' : MEnd, 'TStart' : TStart, 'TEnd' : TEnd, 'WStart' : WStart, 'WEnd' : WEnd, 'RStart' : RStart, 'REnd' : REnd, 'FStart' : FStart, 'FEnd' : FEnd, 'WeekendStart' : WeekendStart, 'WeekendEnd' : WeekendEnd, 'selectedPreference' : selected} , function(data) {
        $("#resultTblContainer").html(data);
        var resultTbl = $("#resultTblContainer > table").dataTable( {
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bJQueryUI": true
        });
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", $("#tabs").tabs("length")-1);
        resultTbl.css('width', '100%'); //make sure table fills its container
    });

});
```

Comment: could you show some markup please? :)

Comment: Certainly, okay so basically in the POST area. I am submitting a list of items the user inputs (array), along with a series of text inputs which are all of the other variables listed. I am then constructing a table so that the results that can be used later to display the results after the work in the php script has been completed. I honestly don't see anything that could cause it to POST multiple times.

Comment: By the way I am using the DataTables jQuery plugin

Comment: Instead of capturing click event of submit button, try posting the data on submit event of form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `click`-event will be bind more then once. E.g. you can add an [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) before:

```
$("#preferenceSubmit").unbind().click(function() {
    ...
```

Comment: Good thinking, though I wonder how the handler could be bound 16 times after 3 or 4 submissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#preferenceSubmit").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

// other code

});
```

or

```
$("#preferenceSubmit").click(function() {
// other code
return false;
});
```

To prevent form from submitting several times with the button click:

```
var form_submitted = false;
$("#preferenceSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(form_submitted) return false;
    else form_submitted = true;
    // other code
    $.post("search.php", {}, function(data){
        // code here
        form_submitted = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I wonder if that explains why data is submitted twice, four times, eight times, ...?

Comment: I believe "#preferenceSubmit" is the submit button of a form. If so, the form will be submitted unless you return false in the click event function, resulting it in submitting via javascript first, and then usual submit. One more thing, there are chances for the form to be submitted several times when the button is clicked several times. To disable that, you could use a variable that holds the submitted status. e.g : `form_submitted = true;`

Comment: I tried this method prior to my posting here on StackOverflow, but it didn't seem to stop the doubling of post submissions. Adding the unbind seemed to have fixed my problem.

Comment: Anyway, glad that you fixed it :) Happy coding!